# Update value with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like update a value in mongoose the value is in two arrays so it doesn't work.

This is the way that I use to access to value with a console.log.

```
console.log('MyValue',bestClustering.cluster_importance[0].feature_importance[0].name)
```

Not simple.

And this is my request to update value

```
var value = {
  'cluster_importance[0].feature_importance[0].name': 'toto'
}
ClusterImportance.update({
  "_id": bestId,
  "cluster_importance[0].cluster": clusterNumber
}, {
  $set: {
    value
  }
})
```

I read the mongoose doc that works with one array, but not two arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code,

```
console.log('MyValue',bestClustering.cluster_importance[0].feature_importance[0].name)
```

suppose it output `MyValue John`

Use `[..]` to get variable's **value** as the **key**.

```
var value = {
  [bestClustering.cluster_importance[0].feature_importance[0].name]: 'toto'
}
ClusterImportance.update({
  "_id": bestId,
  [bestClustering.cluster_importance[0].cluster]: clusterNumber
}, {
  $set: {
    value
  }
})
```

---

**More examples:**

```
const mistake = 'key';

const obj1 = { 'mistake': 5}
console.log(obj1.mistake); // 5

const obj2 = { mistake: 5 }
console.log(obj2.key) // undefined

const obj3 = { [mistake]: 5 }
console.log(obj3.key) // 5
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your code but node tells me that cluster_importance is not define. So I test like that.

var value = {
  '[cluster_importance[0].feature_importance[0].name]': 'toto'
}

With ' ' but don't working :(

Comment: I edit my answer, you should explain better which `key:value` pair you trying to achieve.